# jQuery.css("width") table th

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, width

The problem is, that I configure width of first th on 100px. If you click on the border of column (you mean that you want to resize it). There is one alert. In the alert are width of all th in thead, but they are bad. Look, the size of first th is 100px but in the alert is other value e.g. 49px. I use Google Chrome web-browser. Please help me! I give here fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/xjwVf/3/

Comment: The other values are set in percentages, so it looks like it's working correctly to me?

Comment: We are speaking just about first th in thead. Others are just for example.

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do here?

Comment: I set the first $("th.1") width to 100px. If i want to resize the table, the width displayed in alert is other. E.g. 49px in my browser.

Comment: Currently, whats happening is if you increase the width of the first `th`, the width of the other headers are adjusted relatively. So, is it that you want to increase the overall table width keeping the other `th` widths constant.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your fixed width `<th>`'s display to `inline-block`, it'll force the element to have the specified width.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xjwVf/4/)**

Comment: That's ok. The real width th corresponds with the display width in alert.

Comment: I just now try it.That's no ok. If you use the  `display:inline-block` for all th, it looks bad. http://jsfiddle.net/xjwVf/8/

Comment: Yes, you should set `display:inline-block` for elements with `width`s in `px`.. Keep the elements with percentage width with the default display.

Comment: Yes, I want change all percentage to px. There is no change with or without percentage.

Comment: I've added `display:inline-block;` to all your `th`s and `td`s through CSS to reduce the tag soup and gave the `th`s defined px widths, [check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/xjwVf/9/).

Comment: The only issue then is when the whole table doesn't fit your browser window and it gets resized to fit the window. I'd suggest using `inline-block` `span`s to simulate a table, they are much more easier to handle and keep cross-browser consistent than those pesky table cells.

Comment: Or, if you're setting a fixed width to your table columns, set a `table` width corresponding to the sum of all your columns to prevent it from resizing. http://jsfiddle.net/xjwVf/11/

Comment: Css syntax `th td { /* anything */ }​` is bad. This is right `th, td {/* anything */}`. I just solved this problem.